running 'git status' shows modified and untracked files even when there are no changes by me
I am trying to contribute to the chromium project.
I downloaded the code a few weeks back and recently I was ready to make changes in the code. So I decided to fetch the new code and pull the changes to my local main branch.
On running 'git status' as I have not made any changes to the code I expect my main branch to be up to date with the remote main branch. But instead it says up to date which is as expected but it also shows modified and untracked files even though I haven't made any changes to the code.
C:\chromium\src>git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   docs/website (new commits)
        modified:   third_party/angle (new commits)
        modified:   third_party/boringssl/src (new commits)
        modified:   third_party/catapult (new commits)
        modified:   third_party/chromium-variations (new commits)
        modified:   third_party/crossbench (new commits)
        modified:   third_party/dawn (new commits)
        modified:   third_party/depot_tools (new commits)
        modified:   third_party/devtools-frontend/src (new commits)
        modified:   third_party/ink/src (new commits)
        modified:   third_party/libaom/source/libaom (new commits)
        modified:   third_party/libc++/src (new commits)
        modified:   third_party/libc++abi/src (new commits)
        modified:   third_party/libvpx/source/libvpx (new commits)
        modified:   third_party/libwebp/src (new commits)
        modified:   third_party/llvm-libc/src (new commits)
        modified:   third_party/openscreen/src (new commits)
        modified:   third_party/pdfium (new commits)
        modified:   third_party/perfetto (new commits)
        modified:   third_party/skia (new commits)
        modified:   third_party/webgpu-cts/src (new commits)
        modified:   third_party/webrtc (new commits)
        modified:   third_party/xnnpack/src (new commits)
        modified:   v8 (new commits)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        tools/page_cycler/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

I ran git submodule update  but it opens a git credential manager window and asks for credentials for "chrome-internal.googlesource.com" which I don't have.
What should I do to get a clean branch that I can work on ?

If the cloned repository is https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main its https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/.gitmodules contains a lot of submodules from https://chrome-internal.googlesource.com/ How have you cloned them?

I haven't explicitly cloned the submodules. Initially to get the checkout I used the command fetch chromium provided by depot_tools . To update the code I used git fetch origin and git rebase origin/main.

It seems the repo cannot be updated with Git unless you're a Google employee and have access to chrome-internal.googlesource.com. May be this could help: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/linux/build_instructions.md#update-your-checkout ? If not, you need to fetch clean code yet another time.

On running the updation commands for windows (I have a windows machine) ,that are - git rebase-update and gclient sync -D , the later shows some error . And on running git status  there  are no modified files but the untracked file still shows.
`
C:\chromium\src>git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.
Untracked files:
(use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
tools/page_cycler/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
`

the error is too big to paste here , but I will give the last line: " File "C:\src\depot_tools\auth.py", line 245, in get_access_token
raise GitLoginRequiredError()
auth.GitLoginRequiredError: You are not logged in. Please login first by running:
git-credential-luci login".

"nothing added to commit but untracked files present" Untracked files… may be they could be simply removed? "the error is too big to paste here" Massive updates should be added to the question; [edit], add and format, thus you can add a lot of new info and format for readability.

I tried to fetch new code using fetch --no-history chromium , but it gives same error - " File "C:\src\depot_tools\auth.py", line 245, in get_access_token
raise GitLoginRequiredError()
auth.GitLoginRequiredError: You are not logged in. Please login first by running:
git-credential-luci login"
